# Add Post and Comment SDK in Android

Tags: android, facebook, sdk

Is there any SDK which can be used to let users post a topic and let other users comment on that topic? Something similar to Facebook posts which can be used to create localized social connectivity between users.

I have already searched a lot for this but didn't got any relevant sdk.

Sorry to ask generalized question, but I would like to use a library for this as this is not the main feature of the app, and I don't want to spend much time in developing this from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding you well, you need an API which connects you to a social media framework, which you still need to create. (since it is not Facebook, Twitter or any other social media platform)

The best approach to do this is to create a database which holds an id for reach post a user will be making.

Each time a user comments on a post, the post id is needed to combine the comment with the initial post. The same needs to be done for likes.

In the end it would be a sort of old fashioned forum, whereby a user initially posts a question, and they would get several answers to that questions. Very similar to StackOverflow itself if you may.

The difficult part would be to then integrate the back end to the front end and display the comments/likes in your app. You also need to cater for the connection between comments/likes and the users of your system, since it will always be a user who makes an initial post and another user who likes/comments on that post.

It is quite a complex system to be honest, and if you aren't ready to dedicate time to develop it, I'd rather integrate to an existing social media platform such as Facebook. There are several APIs out there (if you don't want to integrate your app directly with Facebook) such as SocialAuth or even custom libraries on GitHub which can definitely help you.